# Which road bike to match turbo trainer?

Tags: road-bike, cassette, compatibility, beginner, turbo-trainer

Evening all,

Looking for advice please.

As a complete beginner, I'm unsure which type of road bike to match up with a Tacx Flux S Direct Drive Smart Trainer.

It has a this specification:
Compatibility: Bike & Axle: Race: 130mm; MTB: 135mm; Cassette & Wheel : Shimano & SRAM: 8 t/m 11 speed

Would a Carrera Virtuoso Womens Road Bike 2020 with a Shimano CS-HG50 8 Speed, 11-28t fit?

Please help

Comment: Aside - you could also use a cheaper second-hand bike effectively on your trainer.  There's no need to buy a new bike.

Comment: Almost any road bike that has been made in the past 20 years will work. You would need to find something pretty exotic for it not to fit.

Comment: Except Wiggles Brand X Road bike.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that [this link at Halfords](https://www.halfords.com/bikes/road-bikes/carrera-virtuoso-womens-road-bike-2020---blue---s-m-l-frames-348654.html) is the same model you have. As links to online retailers are often impermanent, I'm reproducing one of Halfords' pictures of the bike, focusing on the front fork. I chose this picture in particular because it appears to confirm that you have a quick release fork. The page stated that the Virtuoso had Shimano Claris, an 8-speed groupset.

[image]

[Tacx's description](https://tacx.com/product/flux-s-smart/) of the Flux S says that it comes with a quick release, and that it's compatible with quick releases, so on that score you are good to go. One thing to note for the future is that most current disc brake bikes come with thru axles, which do the same thing as quick releases but have different dimensions. I may be mistaken, but it does not seem that Tacx package thru axle adapters with the trainer. They would be available for purchase aftermarket if you upgrade your bicycle later on.

The freehub body was described as being compatible with 8 to 11 speed Shimano cassettes. You would want to either get a second 8s cassette to use on your trainer, or to remove the cassette from your rear wheel to put it onto the bike. Unless you want to bring the bike and trainer to your local bike shop (LBS) every time you want to change things over, you should get the necessary tools - a lockring tool and a chain whip - and learn to do it yourself. For now, it would be simpler to just buy a second cassette and have the LBS mount it. I believe you will need to put a spacer on the freehub body to enable it to run 8 (or 9 or 10) speed cassettes, and I think the spacer usually comes with the freehub body. So, don't throw away any of the stuff in your package just yet.

Comment: Thank you for your help!